# When I modify the index in slapd.conf the same LDAP query does not return the data

Tags: ldap, indexing

I am using openLDAP on a CENTOS server.

To test I use JMETER with LDAP query and my software using thoses entry.

I want to optimize a particular request, I heavily search an OU attribute : description. The search use the l attribute to find it :search filter `l=username`. 
If my index (in slapd.conf)is :

```
index ou,description,l           eq,pres,sub
```

Jmeter does not return the description field and my software does not allow me to log anymore.

If I remove this line from slapd.conf or if I use  : `index ou,description           eq,pres,sub i have the same average response time.

How can I optimize my perfs?
Why indexing l remove the attribute i want from the answer, and make my software unable to use my directory anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Every* time you add or remove an index you have to run `slapindex` and remember to keep the right permissions for database files. For example, on debian with OpenLDAP you have to:

```
/etc/init.d/slapd stop
slapindex
chown openldap:openldap /var/lib/ldap/*
/etc/init.d/slapd start
```

Comment: If i run slapindex i have the following error :


'bdb(dc=ldapserver,dc=com): Lock table is out of available locks
=> bdb_idl_insert_key: c_put id failed: Cannot allocate memory (12)
=> bdb_tool_entry_reindex: txn_aborted! Accessing a corrupted shared library (80)'

I do not have any openldap user.

Comment: have you stopped slapd before running slapindex? As I mentioned, the openldap user is correct for debian, it may be different on different distributions. Add those errors to question, they don't look good to me, you may have damaged your database...

Comment: Ok, i am recreating a blank directory and using backup this time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this

`sudo /etc/init.d/slapd stop`

`sudo -u insert-your-openldap-server-user-here -c slapindex -v`

`sudo  /etc/init.d/slapd start`

So on my debian box the user is `openldap`, which makes the command look like

`sudo -u openldap slapindex -v -d 1`

Answer (score 0):

Though the original poster's answer is solved, here's a solution to OpenLDAP 2.4 users. OpenLDAP 2.4 does not use plain config files anymore, but everything has to be modified using `ldapmodify`.

First you need to identify your database in question.

```
[root@ldap-server ~]# cd /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config
[root@ldap-server cn=config]# ls
cn=schema       olcDatabase={0}config.ldif     olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif
cn=schema.ldif  olcDatabase={-1}frontend.ldif  olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif
```

The database here is `olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif` and checking for indexes with grep yields:

```
[root@ldap-server cn=config]# grep olcDbIndex olcDatabase\=\{2\}hdb.ldif
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq,pres
olcDbIndex: ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname eq,pres,sub
```

If I need to add, for instance, the poster's index `l`, I'd prepare the following ldif-file:

```
[root@ldap-server ~]# cat ldap-hdb-tuning.ldif
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: ou,description,l eq,pres,sub
```

The final step would be running the file with `ldapmodify`.

```
[root@ldap-server ~]# ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -D cn=config -f ldap-hdb-tuning.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config"
```

If you then look into `/var/lib/ldap` you'll notice a new index.file named `l.bdb` which should be growing if you add new records.
Note that I didn't find out yet if the index creation is being done on the fly for *existing records* (I'm currently doing that right now) but I will adapt this answer when I know more.